# Combinatorics of reduced words in a finite group

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, metric-spaces, algebraic-graph-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

This might be a rather broad question, and I'll be satisfied with some intuition and pointers to relevant literature. However, I'll certainly fill in more context and details based on any feedback. Also, this is a crosspost from MathOverflow, where it didn't get much response, maybe because it isn't research level? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270758/concentration-of-reduced-words

Suppose we have a finite group $G$ of size $n$ and a symmetric generating set $S \subset G$ of size $d$, consider the reduced words formed using $S$ and their images in $G$. A reduced word is a word over the alphabet $S$ that does not contain a subword of the form $s^{-1}s$ or $s s^{-1}$ for $s \in S$.

I'd like to find a small enough subset $B \subset G$ (say $|B|=n/d$) such that "many" reduced words of length $k$ not only evaluate to an element of $B$ but stay within $B$ at each step on the way. That is, suppose $s_1 s_2 \dots s_k$ is a reduced word. Then
$$s_1s_2 \dots s_j \in B$$
for every $1 \leq j \leq k$.

This can also be visualized as a reduced walk on the corresponding Cayley graph staying within a subset $B$. In that interpretation, we would be interested in the quality of sampling vertices using a random (reduced) walk on the graph. This is closely related to graph expansion and the Ramanujan property.

Anyway, so given a group $G$ and generating set $S$, I am interested in the choice of $B \subset G$ of small size so that there are as many reduced words of length $k$ entirely within $B$ as possible. Two candidate choices I am trying out for $B$ are:

1) A ball around $1$ of appropriately large radius

2) A subgroup constructed using a subset of $S$

Are my candidates reasonable? Essentially this is a kind of isoperimetric problem, and more than finding the worst set $B$ algorithmically, my real aim is to seek out a group (and generating set) such that for all small subsets $B$, the number of reduced words of length $k$ staying within $B$ is asymptotically small as $k$ grows large.

I do realize all this might depend heavily on the precise group and generating set. So for concreteness, I'm working with $PSL(2,q)$ as the group. 
However, I am not very clear what properties of the group are reflected in this kind of sampling. I did look at Gromov-type theories, but got a bit lost.

As I mentioned in the beginning, I'll gladly refine the question and make it more narrow if recommended so. As of now am just lost since this isn't my area, and I'll be delighted with just some pointers at least.

Comment: I'm having difficulty unpacking the setup of your Question.  I get as far as $G$ being an (arbitrary) finite group of size $n$, and that $S$ is a set of generators.  I'm not sure what your notion of "symmetric" means (applied to $S$) nor what it means for "reduced words of length $k$" to "evaluate" to a subset $B$ of $G$.  Perhaps there are implied relations that go along with the generators $S$?  Simply saying $s_1 s_2 \ldots s_k \in B$ seems a misconception unless $S\subset G$.

Comment: @hardmath The standard meaning of a symmetric generating set $S$ for $G$ is a subset $S \subset G$ that generates $G$ and that has the property $S=S^{-1}$.

Comment: On more shaky ground, I will hazard a guess that a "reduced word formed using $S$" means a word in which no generator is adjacent to its inverse. This is indeed what it would mean in the context where $S$ is a symmetrized basis for a free group, but in this finite group context I am less sure.

Comment: @LeeMosher is right. I assumed the notion of a reduced word was fairly standard and didn't have to be redefined rigorously. I'll edit the question to clear it up anyway.

Comment: Beyond those issues, I'm unsure what's being asked. The only actual question is too vague.

Comment: True, I was apprehensive about that as well. But I am mainly looking for some geometric intuition about small subsets which contain "many" reduced words. I'll try to make the question more precise.

Comment: I think you can look up "almost convexity" (in connected graphs, and thus, going through Cayley-graphs, in groups): it isn't exactly what you're looking for, but the problematic is similar.

Comment: What if all $s_k$ are selfinverse? I.e. $s_k^2=1$, then this is reduced anyway...

Comment: @draks... Hi, been a while since we talked. Got offtracked, should catch up. And yes, if $s_k$ are all involutions, then this reduces to a simpler case. Just like if the group were abelian, this would be another simple case. But I am interested in how different reduced can be from non-reduced. In our terms, how different is non-backtracking when it comes to sampling? The mixing rate has been studied, but the sampling quality is still vague.

Comment: @draks... As it would have been clear by now, I am investigating the sampling quality of nonbacktracking walks on Ramanujan graphs. With backtracking, we could use some matrix norm bounds to get non-trivial results. But in the nonbacktracking situation, the matrices are all non-commutative and messed up, so I am looking into the more concrete Cayley setting to reduce it to studying groups and words.

Comment: @Max Thanks for the suggestion. Looks interesting.